# Create every combination of variable groups up to order n

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

**SPECIFICATION**

Given `m` variables, create every combination up to order `n`. For example,

The output of mapping two variables (`a` and `b`) to order `1` would be:

- a
- b
- a b

The output of mapping two variables (`a` and `b`) to order `2` would be:

- a
- a<sup>2</sup>
- b
- b<sup>2</sup>
- a b
- a<sup>2</sup> b
- a b<sup>2</sup>
- a<sup>2</sup> b<sup>2</sup>

The output of mapping two variables (`a` and `b`) to order `3` would be:

- a
- a<sup>2</sup>
- a<sup>3</sup>
- b
- b<sup>2</sup>
- b<sup>3</sup>
- a b
- a<sup>2</sup> b
- a<sup>3</sup> b
- a<sup>3</sup> b<sup>2</sup>
- a b<sup>2</sup>
- a b<sup>3</sup>
- a<sup>2</sup> b<sup>3</sup>
- a<sup>2</sup> b<sup>2</sup>
- a<sup>3</sup> b<sup>3</sup>

The output of mapping three variables (`a`, `b`, and `c`) to order `1` would be:

- a
- b
- c
- a b
- b c
- a c
- a b c

The output of mapping `m` variables to order `n` would be:

- etc.

**WINNING CRITERIA**

Output every possible combination as outlined above. Order does not matter. Where in your code you print to the screen does not matter. All that matters is that what shows up in your output is correct.

Comment: How are we intended to output?  Should we use `^`?

Comment: Can we raise things to the zero or one (e.g. a^1)

Comment: What if `m` is greater than 26? do we have to support values that high?

Comment: You can use anything to indicate the order but `^` would probably be easier for a console application. The app shouldn't actually do the calculation, it should just print `x^2`. So, while raising to `0` is okay, it should print `x^0`, not `1`. If the application is limited to only printing the order up to some number that is fine, as long as the algorithm itself is capable of printing to an arbitrary order.

Comment: @user1873073 the problem isn't the maximum order but the maximum number of variable names.

Comment: It should be able to handle an arbitrary number of variables as well. So in that case aa,bb,cc or 27,28,29, or whatever convention you might choose is fine.

Comment: What are we expected to do when the number of variables is greater than the number of letters?

Comment: How will the variables be given? many of the comments assume the input will be a number of variables, but the text `given m variables` implies a list of variables will be given. If only the number of variables is given and 0,1,2,3..27,28,29 raised to powers ^0,^1,^2 etc is acceptable output (as I am inferring from your last comment) it makes things easier.

Comment: Is it ok to output `aa` instead of `a^2`?

Comment: @LevelRiverSt sorry if this response doesn't answer your question. The input is an array of characters. So the ^n is just for decoration for the purpose of this assignment.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma yep, thats fine. Any convention you choose is fine as long as it does the job.

Comment: unmarked it. didn't know how these things are supposed to work.

Comment: @user1873073 *The input is an array of characters*.  So is the input `2 a,b,c` acceptable for the n=2, m=3 case?  If so, I can simplify my answer.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma yeah, of course. im amazed btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
j₎o⊇ᵘb
```

Takes input as a couple, containing the list of variables and the order. Output is a list of lists of variables, where powers are represented by repeated variables. (e.g. "a²b" is ["a","a","b"])

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@5/1qKkv/1FX@8OtM5L@/4@OVkpU0lFKUorVMYr9HwUA)

`j₎` joins the first input with itself as many times as stated by the second input. `o` orders the list obtained, and then `⊇ᵘ` finds all unique subsets of that ordered list. Finally, we remove the first element with `b`, since this will always be the empty answer, which is not contemplated by the challenge.

Answer (score 14):

## L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X, 354 bytes

When I saw this I knew it had to be done in Latex.  Equations just look so crisp and clean in Latex and I can't stand using `^` for power.

```
\documentclass{article}\input tikz\usepackage{intcalc}\usepackage{ifthen}\begin{document}\typein[\a]{}\typein[\b]{}\foreach\x in{1,...,\intcalcPow{\b+1}{\a}}{\begin{equation}\foreach[count=\i]\y in{a,...,z}{\ifthenelse{\(\i<\a\)\OR\(\i=\a\)}{\y^\intcalcDiv{\intcalcMod{\x}{\intcalcPow{\b+1}{\i}}}{\intcalcPow{\b+1}{\i-1}}}{}}\end{equation}}\end{document}
```

### Explanation

There are three main forces at work here `\typein`  which is what allows us to take input from the command line, the `intcalc` package which is what allows us to make calculations with our variables, and the Latex`equation` environment.

---

Once we have taken in input we begin a loop we loop `\intcalcPow{\b+1}{\a}` times, once for each result we want to print.  Each loop we begin an `equation` environment and loop through the alphabet keeping track of `\y` for the current letter and `\i` for the current number of runs.  If `\i` is greater than or equal to `\a` we don't print anything at all (according to the specs this is not strictly necessary however Latex will overflow for values greater than 1 if we don't do this).  We then print `\y` to our equation and raise it to the power of

```
\intcalcDiv{\intcalcMod{\x}{\intcalcPow{\b+1}{\i}}}{\intcalcPow{\b+1}{\i-1}}
```

That whole mess simply means take the `\i`th digit of `\x` in base `\b+1`.  This ensures that the powers are decoded properly.

#### Example output:

Here is the output for 3, 2

[image: Output]

Comment: Note that your output includes a^0 b^0 c^0 = 1, while the test cases do not. That being said, I think you're right and the test cases are wrong :)

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, mathematically speaking the empty set should be in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Comment: @KarlNapf An expression equal to 1 is not the empty set. Nor is a tuple containing 3 zeros.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, not in the specification of this golf. It is like the powerset of (for n=3) {a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c} without the empty set

Comment: @KarlNapf It's *mathematically* not the same. There is no empty set involved here. The challenge involves generating a set of tuples of specified length.

Comment: @jpmc26 Powerset of {a,b} is { {}, {a}, {b}, {ab} } and this challenge states for {"ab",1} -> {{a}, {b}, {ab}} which is the powerset without the empty set.

Comment: @KarlNapf The power set of `{a, b}` does not include `a^2 b^2`. It's not the appropriate model for this problem. Also, it just sunk in that you used `{a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c}` above. That's not a set, since sets can't contain duplicates. This problem is best modeled as *m*-tuples (tuples of length *m*, where *m* is the number of variables as in the question) of integers, which each member of the tuple representing the power of one of the variables.

Comment: @jpmc26 That is way i said "like the powerset". There is a multiset or a family which is an unordered tuple or a set that may contain duplicates. A powerset of this without the empty set is this challenge.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```
Rest[1##&@@@PowerRange[1,#^#2,#]~Distribute~List]&
```

Assumes "given `m` variables" means the first input is a list of variables.

**If first input is an integer, 69 bytes**

```
Rest[1##&@@@PowerRange[v=Unique[]~Table~#;1,v^#2,v]~Distribute~List]&
```

The variables are in the form `$<integer>` (e.g. `$5`)

Comment: TIL `PowerRange` is a thing! I agree with the interpretation of your first submission btw

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>71</s> <s>58</s> <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```
n#m=tail$concat<$>mapM(\x->(\i->x<$[1..i])<$>[0..n])m
```

Returns a list of strings and uses the output format `"aabbb"` for `"a^2 b^3"`.

Usage example: `3 # "ab"` -> `["b","bb","bbb","a","ab","abb","abbb","aa","aab","aabb","aabbb","aaa","aaab","aaabb","aaabbb"]`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@nnGtbkpiZo5Kcn5ecWGKjYpebWOCrEVOha6cRk6lrV2GjEm2op5cZqwmUijbQ08uL1cz9n5uYmadgqwBSqlBQWhJcUuSTp6CiYKygrKCUmJSs9B8A).

Many bytes are spent for output formatting. A more flexible output, e.g. pairs of (variable, power) -> `[('a',2),('b',3),('c',1)]` for `"a^2 b^3 c^1"` would save a lot.

How it works

```
    mapM(\x->    )m      -- for each variable x in the input list m
      \i->x<$[1..i]      -- make i copies of x
             <$>[0..n]   -- for all numbers from 0 to n
                         -- in fact mapM makes all possible combinations hereof, i.e.
                         -- [["",""], ["", "b"], ["", "bb"] ... ["a",""], ["a","b"], ...]
  concat<$>              -- join all inner lists 
                         --    e.g ["aa","bbb"]  -> "aabbb"
tail                     -- drop the first (all powers = ^0)
```

With maximum flexibility, i.e. output format as (variable, power) pairs and including all-zero powers (`"a^0 b^0 c^0"`) it boils down to

#### Haskell, 25 bytes:

```
f n=mapM((<$>[0..n]).(,))
```

Usage example: `f 2 "ab"`:

```
[[('a',0),('b',0)],
 [('a',0),('b',1)],
 [('a',0),('b',2)],
 [('a',1),('b',0)],
 [('a',1),('b',1)],
 [('a',1),('b',2)],
 [('a',2),('b',0)],
 [('a',2),('b',1)],
 [('a',2),('b',2)]]
```

Dropping all-zero powers costs 5 bytes for a total of 30: `f n=tail.mapM((<$>[0..n]).(,))`.

Comment: For your second code, `[('a',0),('b',0)]` should not be in the output...

Comment: @JungHwanMin: my 25-byte solution is not meant to be an answer. It's a note to show that the combinatoric part of the challenge needs the least number of bytes - at least in Haskell. Dropping `a^0 b^0` costs 5 bytes. I'll add another note.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>20</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṗj€“”Ṣ€
ŒPçÐ€j“”Q
```

A dyadic link (function) that accepts a list of variable names* and the maximal order (an integer) and returns a list where each entry is a fully expanded representation of the multiplication (e.g. **foo<sup>0</sup>bar<sup>3</sup>bof<sup>2</sup>** would be `['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bof', 'bof']`.

* the variable names may be a string of unique characters (strings become lists of characters).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w5/SsR01rHjXMedQw9@HORUA219FJAYeXH54AZGZBxAP/H17uDeRG/v8frZ6Wn6@uo56UWAQk0/KT1GP/mwAA)** - the footer calls the link as a dyad and then separates the resulting list of lists by line feeds and each entry by spaces for ease of reading.

*Note:* includes the **0** order (empty product) a dequeue, `Ḋ`, may be inserted here `...ŒPḊç...` to avoid that.

#### How?

```
ṗj€“”Ṣ€ - Link 1, sorted results of a Cartesian power: elements, power
ṗ       - Cartesian power of elements with given power
 j€“”   - join €ach with "" (flatten each by one level)
     Ṣ€ - sort €ach

ŒPçÐ€j“”Q - Main link: variableNames, maximalOrder
ŒP        - power-set of variableNames (e.g for ['a','b','c'] this would be ['','a','b','c','ab','ac','bc','abc'])
   Ð€     - for €ach mapped over right argument (i.e. over the range [1,2,...,maximalOrder])
  ç       -     call the last link (1) as a dyad (i.e. power-set results are the elements and one of the range values is the power)
     j“”  - join with "" (flatten by one level)
        Q - unique values
```

---

13 byte version that will only work for a single string of unique characters (or a list of unique characters):

```
ŒPṗÐ€j“”F€Ṣ€Q
```

[try it](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390UsDDndMPT3jUtCbrUcOcRw1z3YDMhzsXAcnA/4eXR/7/r56YlKz@3wgA)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 100 bytes

Surely there is a more efficient way to accomplish this!

Two variables to order 4:

```
(Times@@@(MapThread[Power,#]&/@Outer[List,{Alphabet[][[1;;#]]},Rest@Tuples[Range[0,#2],#],1][[1]])) &
```

[image: picture]

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + sed, 60

A different, shorter approach to my previous answer.

Input as command-line parameters - `m` is given as a comma-separated list of variable names, and `n` as an integer:

```bash
p=eval\ printf
$p -vc %s {$1}^\\{0..$2}
$p '%s\\n' $c|sed 1d
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#PYtBCoMwFAX3nuIRIm6MNHbX0pt8CmnypUJJgglurGdPLba@zTwYZggTMqdsTWKMHsK0D2ixs//xvLO1m7nChYrtM0AcHQn5/yQuosK2xBlK4RAl3ng2L0KcRp@HSkao2aJOWKRe70TLqetkv35FUyci30Dad2IH7YoLnssH).

---

Previous Answer:

## Bash + coreutils, 91

Welcome to eval-escape-brace hell.  Sometimes shell-script really gives just the right tool for the job.  This is **not** the case here, but it works.

Input as command-line parameters - `m` is given as a comma-separated list of variable names, and `n` as an integer.  Output is written out longhand - e.g. `a^2` is actually written `aa`.  This is acceptable as per [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/112611/create-every-combination-of-variable-groups-up-to-order-n?noredirect=1#comment274481_112611).

```bash
p=eval\ printf
$p -vc {%$[$2-1]s}
$p '%s\\n' $($p %s \{{$1}${c// /,}\\\,})|tr -d {}|sort -u
```

There may be shorter ways to do this.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#PY29DsIwDIT3PsUpSgVIiarCBmJiYGXHDCVNoVJJqiQwEPLspfze8vl8sq@xDkH7oCqv0RqwShxRsg/nXy4@FOqd7Jw9uepyac1J7K73e6e92Nhai63tmvFmhdpmWp0t2P8zMf6biS1ZhlFeB0iJfzD0a32rOkLvWhOajPeQN4WY8z2fy/Lg02s1yT2RmYBPR5N7UIy8TDyqokAhEhGJNHsEB1kjpoe3bmy5DrU1engC).

## Explanation

- `printf -vc {%$[$2-1]s}` assigns the variable `c` to a string like `{   }`, where the number of spaces is the order `n` - 1, so if `n` = 1, the result is `{}`, if `n` = 2, the result is `{ }`, etc.
- `${a[$1]}` uses `m` as an index to the array `a`, so if `m` is 3, then the result is `c`
- `\{{a..${a[$1]}}${c// /,}\\,}` is a multi-part brace expansion:

  - `\{` - a literal `{`
  - `{$1}` is a is the brace expansion of the list `m`, e.g. `{a,b,c}` or `a b c`
  - `${c// /,}` replaces the spaces in `$c` with commas, e.g. `{,,}` for `n` = 3, which is also a brace expansion which effectively repeats each element of `{a..c}` `n` times
  - `\\\,}` - a literal `,}`
- So for `m` = "a,b" and `n` = 2, this expands to `{a,} {a,} {b,} {b,}`
- The inner `printf` removes the spaces to give `{a,}{a,}{b,}{b,}`, which itself is a brace expansion
- This expands to `aabb aab aab aa abb ab ab a abb ab ab a bb b b`
- The outer `printf` puts each of these elements on its own line
- `sort -u` removes the duplicates
- The `tr -d {}` is there to handle the case when `n` = 1.  In this case the variable `c` will be `{}` which is not a brace expansion, but instead the literal characters are inserted.  The `tr` removes them.

`eval`s and `\` escapes are placed *very* carefully to ensure that all the expansions occur in the necessary order.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES proposal), 142 bytes

```js
f=
(v,n)=>[...Array(++v**n)].map((_,i)=>i.toString(v).padStart(n,0).replace(/./g,(c,j)=>(+c?(10+j).toString(36):``)+(c>1?c.sup():``))).join`<br>`
```

```html
<div oninput=o.innerHTML=f(v.value,n.value)><input id=v type=number min=1 value=1><input id=n type=number min=1 value=1><span id=o><br>a
```

Requires a browser with both `**` and `padStart` support, so try Firefox 52 or Chrome 57.

Answer (score 3):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>49</s> <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
f n{r=[""]{|v|r=r...[seq(0,n)|[v.._]]}_;r[1:]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#DcSxCoAgEADQub7iuEkhjmos@hIRKUhySOwqF/XbrTe8asEnXhSiTjlmXpiI1L1fou@8zCoSGa2LmVkNky71XJ2H1DbhvQ@BK3aAG0rIYGH8D@z8A6Yt9QM)

I think it is correct. It doesn't use any separator between a variable and its order. The previous version used `!`, but I realized that it isn't strictly required.

Explained:

```
function f(n) {
    r := [""] /* r is a list with one empty string. */
    /* Loops over the variable names in the stream. */
    for var do
        /* Concatenates every element in r to */
        /* every element in the list that contains orders of */
        /* variable var. */
        r = r...[
            push(var..x) for x in [seq(0, n)]
        ]
    done
    r[1:] /* Return elements of r not counting the first. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 112 bytes

```
import itertools as t
f=lambda n,v:[''.join(map(str.__mul__,v,I))for I in t.product(range(n),repeat=len(v))][1:]
```

Usage:

```
for x in f(3, 'ab'):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
b
bb
a
ab
abb
aa
aab
aabb
```

Nicer format in **115 bytes**:

```
import itertools as t
f=lambda n,v:[''.join(map('{}^{}'.format,v,I))for I in t.product(range(n),repeat=len(v))][1:]
```

Output (same usage):

```
a^0b^1
a^0b^2
a^1b^0
a^1b^1
a^1b^2
a^2b^0
a^2b^1
a^2b^2
```

Even nicer in **125 bytes**:

```
import itertools as t
f=lambda n,v:[''.join(c+'^%s'%i for c,i in zip(v,I)if i)for I in t.product(range(n),repeat=len(v))][1:]
```

Output:

```
b^1
b^2
a^1
a^1b^1
a^1b^2
a^2
a^2b^1
a^2b^2
```

The last 4 bytes (`[1:]`) in all are for removing the empty product.

These work in both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

## C++14, <s>146</s> 140 bytes

-6 byte for simpler output format.

Unnamed lambda, assuming input `s` like `std::string` and `o` as `std::ostream`:

```cpp
[](auto s,int n,auto&o){int l=s.size(),k,c,*p=new int[l]{1};while(!c){for(c=1,k=0;k<l;o<<s[k]<<"^"<<p[k],p[k++]*=!(c=(p[k]+=c)>n));o<<" ";}}
```

Usage and explanation:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

auto f=
[](auto s, int n, auto&o){
 int l=s.size(),              //string length
     k,                       //running variable for l
     c,                       //carry for the increment
    *p=new int[l]{1};         //init array with first elem 1
 while(!c){                   //if carry was leftover, break
  for(
   k=0,c=1;                   //always start with carry                  
   k<l;                       
    o<<s[k]<<"^"<<p[k],       //output
    p[k++]*=!(c=(p[k]+=c)>n)  
//               p[k]+=c      //inc p[k]  
//            c=(p[k]+=c)>n   //if value is greater than order  
//  p[k++]*=!(c=(p[k]+=c)>n)  //set p[k] to 0 and inc k
  );
  o<<" ";                     
 }
}
;

main(){
 f(std::string("ab"),3,std::cout);
 std::cout << "\n";
 f(std::string("abc"),2,std::cout);
}
```

Output:

```cpp
a^1b^0 a^2b^0 a^3b^0 a^0b^1 a^1b^1 a^2b^1 a^3b^1 a^0b^2 a^1b^2 a^2b^2 a^3b^2 a^0b^3 a^1b^3 a^2b^3 a^3b^3 
a^1b^0c^0 a^0b^1c^0 a^1b^1c^0 a^0b^0c^1 a^1b^0c^1 a^0b^1c^1 a^1b^1c^1
```